# Changing values in fancytabs

Tags: fancytabs

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 (64) with XeLaTeX and the Texmaker editor. For an address book for my son's preschool I would like to use `fancytabs` for a thumb index. The package works fine and produces the thumb index as described in the documentation. I do not understand how to change the package's presets, however.

I have some experience with the syntax in TikZ and LaTeX, but, alas, only a rudimentary understanding of programming. I suspect this may be why I cannot answer the following question when reading Raphael Pinson's `fancytabs` documentation: How, exactly, do I change one of the package's parameters for use in a given document document? The `\fancytabsStyle` default, for instance, is `\Large\scshape`. How do I change this default in my preamble so that, for instance, the small caps are no longer in use? I tried altering the "variable" and then the "accessor" (those are the terms in "2 Implementation" of the documentation) for this parameter by adding the following after `\usepackage{fancytabs}`:

```
\newcommand{\tab@style}{\Large}
```

I also tried

```
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\renewcommand{\tab@style}{\Large}
```

and I also tried adding `\newcommand{\tab@style}{\Large}` or `\renewcommand{\tab@style}{\Large}` after `\begin{document}`.

I suspect that there is some basic principle of using commands that is escaping me. If someone could show me how to change a single parameter of `fancytabs` I would be very grateful.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but please also upvote it (this has to be done separately from accepting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the "official" way is

```
\fancytabsStyle{\Large}
```

As `\fancytabsStyle` internally uses `\renewcommand{\tab@style}`, your second approach should also work if you enclose the changed definition within `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` (See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tab@style}{\Large}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you, lockstep, for your help. Not only did your explanation solve my immediate problem, your pointer re. \makeatletter and  \makeatother is quite helpful in a more general sense!

Comment: In general, the package provides setting commands so you don't have to redefine internals (commands with `@`). For more redefinitions, look at https://github.com/cc-translators/sagesse/blob/master/devotional.sty#L423 and following.